# Encountered problem installing XV6 on my MAC OS

Tags: macos, makefile, xv6

I am tring to install XV6 on my MacOS. These are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded xv6 from https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public
2. Installed qemu using `brew install qemu`
3. Installed i386-elf toolchain from https://github.com/nativeos/homebrew-i386-elf-toolchain. Used these commands:

```
brew tap nativeos/i386-elf-toolchain
brew install nativeos/i386-elf-toolchain/i386-elf-binutils
brew install nativeos/i386-elf-toolchain/i386-elf-gcc
```

After cloning the xv6-public repo, I changed the Makefile to the one given in https://github.com/ashr123/XV6-MacOS-Makefile/tree/master

Now I ran `make qemu clean` from the xv6-public directory.

I get this error:

```
i386-elf-gcc -fno-pic -std=gnu17 -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -march=i686 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie   -c -o sh.o sh.c
sh.c: In function 'runcmd':
sh.c:58:1: error: infinite recursion detected [-Werror=infinite-recursion]
   58 | runcmd(struct cmd *cmd)
      | ^~~~~~
sh.c:89:5: note: recursive call
   89 |     runcmd(rcmd->cmd);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sh.c:109:7: note: recursive call
  109 |       runcmd(pcmd->left);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sh.c:116:7: note: recursive call
  116 |       runcmd(pcmd->right);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sh.c:95:7: note: recursive call
   95 |       runcmd(lcmd->left);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sh.c:97:5: note: recursive call
   97 |     runcmd(lcmd->right);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sh.c:127:7: note: recursive call
  127 |       runcmd(bcmd->cmd);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [sh.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand what went wrong.
All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use xv6-riscv - https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv.git instead.

As [REAMDE](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/README#L1-L3) mentioned , xv6-public has not been maintained anymore.